# What does this do? tasklist /m "mscor*"

Tags: .net

Saw this question here : [What Great .NET Developers Ought To Know (More .NET Interview Questions)](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhatGreatNETDevelopersOughtToKnowMoreNETInterviewQuestions.aspx)

Comment: @ leppie: I agree, removed the c# tag. But mscor* should have something to do with .NET?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It will show processes that have loaded modules (usaully .DLL files) hosting the .NET runtime.  The same technique can be used to search for other DLLs that have been loaded.

On a related note, [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) is a Microsoft task manager replacement that will show .NET processes highlighted.  I cannot recommend it enough.  It is well worth investigating along with the rest of the [Sysinternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/0e18b180-9b7a-4c49-8120-c47c5a693683.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

This is a very useful command line tool in windows that shows you a list of all running processes. Passing in a command line parameter of /m "mscor*" lists out all of the processes running on your machine running that are using assemblies that begin with the name "mscor". The "*" is a wildcard character.

Answer (score 2):

It would seem to list all processes using modules like mscoree.dll, mscorwks.dll, etc. This would be .NET processes and possibly processes hosting .NET plug-ins.

Comment: Wow, there are surprisingly few ".NET processes" on my Vista box.

Comment: Yeah, I was getting no results until I opened a PowerShell window.