# How to list all running CLR instances

Tags: clr

Just forgot the command which I used to execute at DOS Prompt to list all running CLR instances on a Machine. Anyone remembers it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tasklist /m mscor***

tasklist /m mscor* will show processes that have loaded modules (usaully .DLL files) hosting the .NET runtime. The same technique can be used to search for other DLLs that have been loaded.

On a related note, [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) is a Microsoft task manager replacement that will show .NET processes highlighted.  I cannot recommend it enough.  It is well worth investigating along with the rest of the [Sysinternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/0e18b180-9b7a-4c49-8120-c47c5a693683.aspx).

See also [What does this do? tasklist /m “mscor*”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152506/what-does-this-do-tasklist-m-mscor)

Answer (score 0):

I have got it - it is tasklist /m mscor*